# In-App-Purchase consumable product managment

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes

In My application I am using consumable in-app-purchase for SMS credit and managing this credit from my server. Application send me the receipt of transaction on server and I verify on server.

But in one of transaction receipt is not received to server but customer money is deducted. So there is any way to verify the purchase on iTunes. So I can check and add balance to client account.

Please suggest. 
I know its not a technical question but its related to developer.

Comment: Consumable purchases cannot be restored, so there is no way of retrieving the receipt once it has been processed.  You should only complete the SKTransaction once you have confirmed that the user's balance has been updated on your server.  If you do this then it should not be possible for the transaction to be lost.